# RewriteRule returning the "EXCESSIVE REDIRECTS" error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I typed in the following code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Essentially, what it is supposed to do is, redirect any request from `/amit/` to `public/$REQUEST.php`. It keeps returning this too much redirect errors in my apache log files and I just can't seem to figure out the issue.

I'm quite novice to apache so please be polite. I would love if you give an explanation with the solution.

Edit 2:
For further information: in the `localhost` root, I have an `.htaccess` to redirect all requests to `/amit/`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) amit/$1 [NC,L]
```

Inside the directory `/amit/`, I have another `.htaccess` to redirect requests to admin/public accordingly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/

RewriteRule ^(admin/|admin)$ admin/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(admin_login/|admin_login)$ public/admin_login/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [NC,L]
```

And finally, inside the `/amit/public/` directory, I have another one to process requests within the directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/public/

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your rule looks ok. Are there any other rules or directives in your htaccess file?

Comment: Is `public/` a sub-directory inside `/amit/` ?

Comment: Yes, `public/` is inside `amit/`. And `amit` is inside `localhost` directory. Running MAMP... If that helps.

Comment: I've also tried removing all the lines and having just the last one, the same one that's not working. And it didn't work. I tried doing the same in the parent directory, which is `htdocs` to redirect all requests to `/amit/` and it worked... Very weird.

Comment: It seems like something weird is happening with the `public` directory. Anytime that is in the directive, it gives an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Internal Redirect Infinite Loop with mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276590/apache-internal-redirect-infinite-loop-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite simple, but didn't seem that obvious at first.

For the `RewriteCond`, I was using `$` while I am supposed to be using `%`.

It's these keen details that sometimes catch the worst of programmers...