# Apache Internal Redirect Infinite Loop with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Okay, this seems impossible to solve, even with all the solutions already given to similar problems.

Have `.htaccess` file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /amit/public/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Without the `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200` and the rule following the condition, the server goes through infinite loop. The apache log file would look like this:

```
r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities.php
redirected from r->uri = /amit/public/activities
```

Essentially, it will NOT open the file when it evaluates to requested_path.php but will keep on adding more `.php`s.

If I do add in that condition, it will not add .php at all and return 404 error with this line in my log:

```
File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/amit/public/activities
```

Busted closed to 24 hours trying to solve it, no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using `$` instead of `%` for `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That would still cause a redirect loop when the file doesn’t exist. You can check if the extension was added too:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])(?<!\.php)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```